# xlsxwriter python how to execute VBA function in python and export as .xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, vba, xlsxwriter

I've extracted and imported a vba function (autofit all rows) into my python xlsxwriter script. If I open the .xlsm document, I can use the macro via Alt+F8 and it works as expected. But, I'd like to run the macro within python, then export the file as .xlsx

Here is my macro:

```
Sub AutoFitAll()
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkSt As String
    Dim wkBk As Worksheet
    wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name
    For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        wkBk.Activate
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next wkBk
    Sheets(wkSt).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

Here is my command prompt vbaProject.bin extraction

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads> python C:\file\location\vba_extract.py macro\file\location\site_status_macro.xlsm
Extracted: vbaProject.bin
```

Here is my code importing pandas dataframes and adding them to seperate sheets. The last part of my python script is not working -- the script runs fine, but when I open the document, the macro has clearly not been executed.

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col3': [5, 6], 'col4': [7, 8]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col5': [9, 10], 'col6': [11, 12]})

path = 'C:/Users/username/Downloads/' 
filename = path + 'final_export.xlsx'
filename_macro = path + 'final_export.xlsm'

with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:        
    names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
    dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
    
    for df, name in zip(dfs, names): df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
 
    workbook = writer.book
    
    workbook.filename = filename_macro
    workbook.add_vba_project(path + 'vbaProject.bin')


xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=filename_macro, ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("'final_export.xlsm'!AutoFitAll")
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

The last part isn't working. I've successfully imported my macro, but now i want to run it to autofit all rows. how do I run this macro in python? I'd like to run it in python, and then export it to .xlsx file.

Thanks so much for any and all help!

Comment: Do you realize you specified `ReadOnly=1`?  If you've changed something, it won't be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using package `xlwings`.
Install it `pip install xlwings`.

```
import xlwings
excel_app = xlwings.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
excel_book = excel_app.books.open("final_export.xlsm")
run_macro = excel_book.app.macro('Module1.AutoFitAll')
run_macro()
excel_app.quit()
```